# Passing array form to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I send array of model from html view to controller. In this code I receive null on controller parameter.

```
public class PropModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PropModel[] model)
{
        foreach (var r in model)
        {
            //Do somethings
        }
        return View();
}
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                @Html.TextBox("Name")
                @Html.TextBox("Value")
            <br/>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use editor templates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823482/how-to-create-multiple-textbox-with-a-list-of-objects/9823554#9823554

Comment: @Shyju I should use templates editor only or there is another solution?

Comment: I posted an answer with EditorTemplates  solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **EditorTemplates** to handle this situation.

Let's make a new viewmodel for our view.

```
public class PropListVM
{
    public List<PropModel> Props { set; get; }
    public PropListVM()
    {
        Props = new List<PropModel>();
    }
}
```

Now in our `GET` Action, we will create an object of this new viewmodel, Set the `Props` collection and send to our view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{           
    var vm = new PropListVM { Props = GetPropsFromSomeWhere() };
    return View(vm);
}
private List<PropModel> GetPropsFromSomeWhere()
{
    var list = new List<PropModel>();
    //Hard coded for demo. You may replace it with DB items
    list.Add(new PropModel { Name = "Detroit", Value = "123" });
    list.Add(new PropModel { Name = "Ann Arbor", Value = "345" });
    return list;
}
```

Now Let's create an **EditorTemplates**. Go to `~/Views/YourControllerName` and Create a Folder called "EditorTemplates" and create a new view there with the same name as of the Property Name(`PropModel.cshtml`)

[image]

Add this code to your new editor template.

```
@model ReplaceYourNameSpaceHere.PropModel
<div>
    Name :@Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name) <br />
    Value : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Value)
</div>
```

Make sure to replace `ReplaceYourNameSpaceHere` with your actual namespace where the `PropModel` class is available.

Now Let's go back to our original view(`Index.cshtml`) which is strongly typed to an instance of our `PropListVM` viewmodel.

```
@model ReplaceYourNameSpaceHere.PropListVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.Props)        
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
}
```

Now let's have an action method to handle the form posting, You will have a parameter of type `PropListVM` and MVC model binding will bind the properties of this objects from the form posted. You can check the `Props` property of this object and loop through each items.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PropListVM model)
{
    foreach (var prop in model.Props)
    {
        string s = prop.Name;
        //Do cool somethings
    }
    // return or redirect now
    //If we are returning the posted model back to the form, 
    //reload the Props property.
    model.Props = GetPropsFromSomeWhere();
    return View(model);
}
```

And the result is ??? **Profit !!!!!!**

In my example, I sent 2 `PropModel` items with Name and Value properties set, But if you want some empty form, Simply add `PropModel` objects without initializing any property values.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
@model List<PropModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>this.Model[i].Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>this.Model[i].Value)
            <br/>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The magic is in how you name your input fields.

Comment: I do not want use @model in view because this form generated by for (int i = 0; i < **n**; i++) that n will be specified by app configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think the controller will interpret that post as as array of `Name`s and an array of `Value`s.  You could try to either update your method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[] Name, string[] Value)
{

}
```

Or build your "model" as an array of objects using JSON.

Comment: Is it possible I get value in one parameter same as PropModel[], It is important to be sorted indexes for both parameters.